# Display previous week value and difference in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to create a Matrix table that displays four columns

```
- date (in my dataset)
- this weeks value (in my dataset)
- the previous weeks value
- Week on Week difference
- % Difference
```

How do I create a measure that displays the previous weeks value and the week-on-week difference?

Source Data Structure

```
    DATE,       VALUE
    4/11/2019   100    
    11/11/2019  110     
    18/11/2019  130     
    25/11/2019  110
```

The end result would look like this...

```
DATE,       VALUE,  PREVIOUS WEEK, WEEK-ON-WEEK DIFF   % DIFF
4/11/2019   100     90             10                  10%
11/11/2019  110     100            10                  9%
18/11/2019  130     110            20                  15%
25/11/2019  110     130            -20                 -18%
```

So far - I've created a column with *WEEKNUM*, however couldn't figure out the calculation. A solution I'm using for a current week vs previous week is below, however this doesn't work when I'm trying to create a table with multiple previous weeks as shown in the example above.

```
Previous Week = 
  VAR CURRENT_WEEK = WEEKNUM(TODAY()) return
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE(TABLE[VALUE]), 
     FILTER (TABLE,
    WEEKNUM(TABLE[DATE]) = CURRENT_WEEK -1))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source data structure (including calendar table / relationships, as appropriate), your existing code (particularly for the `This Week Value` measure), and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I did it once like this:

I copied my source table (`TableWeek`):

[image]

Add a blank query and use this expression:

```
=TableWeek
```

[image]

Lets call the `Query1` then `TableWeekShift`.
To the table `TableWeek` I added the following calculated column:

```
'Week
=Date.WeekOfYear([Date])
```

To the table `TableWeekShift` I added the following calculated column:

```
'WeekShift
=Date.WeekOfYear(Date.AddWeeks([Date], -1))
```

Now I merged this as new query (`Home > Merge Queries > Merge As New`) by the week and weekshift. When you expand the value you will get this:

[image]

Based on this table you can add two calculated colums with your `week-on-week diff` and `% diff`.